# Which food can be crafted by using which ingredients?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I'm having some problems with crafting food in *Sword of the Stars: The Pit*.

Can someone make a list of all food that can be crafted and list which ingredients need to be used for each?

I will also add any food crafting recipes i find.

Comment: Dont forget the recipies are spoilers :3

Comment: @zeke Recipes definitely don't fall in spoiler category. And it's hard to get most of them on your own since cooker/labs aren't always easy to find and they can only be used few times each. Also if you fail at crafting something you lose your materials, so I'd rather read a list of recipes, instead of wasting all ingredients trying to figure out recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following recipes were accumulated from playthroughs, searching online, the Pitopedeia - http://thepit.0xff.me/, and the SotS : The Pit wikia - http://sword-of-the-stars-the-pit.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_the_Stars:_The_Pit_Wiki.

***Via Cooker / Creation Station / EZ Cooker (Only 3 Slots For Ingredients)***

**Aggressive Antibiotics * 2** = Anti-Bodies + Moldy Bread
**Amino Goop** = Pineal Gland + Pineal Gland + Exotic Proteins + Mutagens
**Anti-Venom * 3** = Poison Gland + Serum
**Bacon and Eggs** = Star-Bacon + Egg
**Baked Avian** = Scent Gland + Avian Carcass
**Base Paste** = Fat Strips + Fat Strips + Bone Slivers
**Berserker Serum** = Adrenal Sack + Serum + Pineal Gland + Giant Mitochondria
**Bird of Feasting** = Avian Carcass + Ancient Herbs + Edible Roots + Apples + Morrigi Flavor Oils
**Blandwich** = Moldy Bread + Raw Meat + Rotten Cheese
**Brain Soup** = Pineal Gland + Pineal Gland + Hiver Brain Crystal + Exotic Proteins + Giant Mitochondria
**Bugboy** = Kirt'ch Grubs + Kutar Oatmix
**Burnt Ribs** = Ribs
**Chocolate Fondue** = Chocolate Eggs + Chocolate Eggs + Bone Slivers + Tarka Warbread + Morrigi Flavor Oils
**Cooked Meat** = Raw Meat
**Counter Poison** = Serum + Shrooms + Fungal Shards + Fungal Shards
**Damper Patch** = Giant Mitochondria + Scent Gland
**Dembo Jam** = Laybliss Berries + Laybliss Berries + Laybliss Berries + Laybliss Berries
**Dermal Enzymes** = Scale Cells + Mutagens + Exotic Proteins
**Dried Fruit** = Laybliss Berries + Apples + Bh'azhnazh Fruit
**Energy Drink** = Exotic Protein + Giant Mitochondria + Primordial Soup
**Epic Bacon Sotswich** = Hero Sotswich + Star-Bacon + Star-Bacon + Star-Bacon + Star-Bacon
**Faux Roast** = Fungal Meat + Fungal Meat + Fungal Meat + Bindings + Bindings
**Fondue** = Bone Slivers + Safe Cheese + Safe Cheese + Stale Bread
**Fortifying Sandwich** = Safe Cheese + Safe Meat + Stale Bread
**Grilled Cheese** = Stale Bread + Safe Cheese
**Healing Salve** = Ancient Herbs + Edible Roots
**Hero Sotswich** = Cooked Meat + Hiver Cheese + Tarka Warbread
**Hoolari Soup * 3** = Hoolari Gourd + Morrigi Flavor Oils
**Hum Gum * 3** = Exotic Proteins + Sonic Nodule
**Maybe Back Ribs** = StarBeQue Sauce + Scent Gland + Ribs + Ribs
**Mitochondrial Stimulator** = Serum + Giant Mitochondria + Chemo Slugs + Omni Gland
**Omelette** = Safe Cheese + Egg + Egg
**Pheromone Bait** = Disease Extract + Scent Gland
**Pit Stew** = Tainted Meat + Ancient Herbs + Edible Roots + Tainted Meat + Fat Strips
**Protein Shake** = Egg + Primordial Soup + Raw Meat + Exotic Proteins
**Pungent Meat** = Raw Meat + Scent Gland
**Rib Sandwich** = Bread + Burnt Ribs
**Roast Beast** = Bindings + Bindings + Raw Meat + Raw Meat + Raw Meat
**Sammich** = Bread + Raw Meat
**Sammich * 5** = Bread + Baked Avian
**Seafood Platter** = Ku'Sulto Lobstercake + Soylent Vines + Wuuna Sea Cucumber
**Sotswich** = Cooked Meat + Tarka Warbread
**Star Fondue** = Chozanti Brie + Safe Cheese + Tarka Warbread + Bone Slivers + Morrigi Flavor Oils
**StarBeQue Sauce** = Nova Fruit + Morrigi Flavor Oils + Ancient Herbs + Primordial Soup
**Steak N Shrooms** = Raw Meat + Shrooms + Shrooms
**Steroidal Enhancers** = Exotic Proteins + Mutagens + Scent Gland + Vitamins
**Steroidal Venom** = Adrenal Sack + Serum + Poison Gland + Scale Cells + Chemo Slugs
**Stinkwich** = Moldy Bread + Pungent Meat + Chozanti Brie
**Stuffed Mushrooms** = Stale Bread + Shrooms + Shrooms
**Trail Mix** = Dried Fruit + Melosian Chocolate + Hofnuts
**Turkey Lasagna** = Leftovers + Leftovers + Hiver Cheese
**Unspeakable Hoagie** = Tarka Warbread + Fungal Meat + Chozanti Brie

***Via Purifier***

**Burnt Ribs** = Ribs
**Medicinal Nuts** = Hofnuts
**Safe Cheese** = Rotten Cheese
**Safe Meat** = Raw Meat
**Safe Meat** = Tainted Meat
**Stale Bread** = Moldy Bread
**Star-Bacon** = Fat Strips

Comment: Accepted your answer since mine is very outdated (because I stopped playing the game).

Answer (score 7):

This are the cooking recipes i have found so far by playing and by checking out posts on forums related to the game. I'll be adding more recipes as i find them.

**Cooked Meat** = Raw Meat
**Sotswich** = Tarka Warbread + Cooked Meat
**Pungent Meat** = Raw Meat + Scent Gland
**Hum Gum** = Sonic Nodule + Exotic Proteins
**Agressive Antibiotics** = Moldy Bread + Anti-Bodies
**Anti-Venom** = Serum + Poison Sac
**Energy Drink** = Exotic Protein + Primordial Soup + Giant Mitochondria
**Fondue** = 2x Safe Cheese + Bone Sliver + Stale Bread
**Fortifying sandwich** = Stale Bread + Safe Meat + Safe Cheese
**Hero Sotswhich** = Cooked Meat + Tarka Warbread + Hiver cheese
**Pheremone Bait** = Desease extract + Scent Gland
**Roast Beast** = 3x Raw Weat + 2x Bindings
**Seafood Platter** = Soylent Vines + Ku'sulto Lobstercake + Wuuna Seacucumber
**Steroidal Enhancers** = Vitamins + Mutagen + Exotic Protein + Scent Gland
**Blandwich** = Moldy Bread + Rotten Cheese + Raw Meat
**Bacon and Eggs** = Star-Bacon + Egg
**Damper Patch** = Giant Mitochondria + Scent Gland
**Star Fondue** = Chozanti Brie + Safe Cheese + Tarka Warbread + Bone Slivers + Morrigi Flavor Oils
**Stinkwich** = Moldy Bread + Pungent Meat + Chozanti Brie
**Base Paste** = Fat Strips + Bone Slivers
**Omelette** = Safe Cheese + Egg + Egg

Comment: How about the lab crafting and such? Found any info about that? I've been looking around and I see some recipes here and there, but nothing that is rather centralized.

Comment: @Lyrion I have over 20 lab recipes (found most on forums, and some by myself). Make a question asking for lab recipes and I'll post them as answer.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108905/what-can-i-make-with-the-lab-station

Answer (score 0):

All mobs, items & recipes: [thePITopedia](http://thepit.0xff.me)

Comment: Could you include the essential parts of your answer here? We try to discourage link-only answers here since they become useless if the linked site goes down.

Comment: And that's not the only problem here. This question asks for cooker only crafting recipes. The link you gave contains everything (lab recipes too, and items that aren't even used as ingredients), and to make it even worse they're all mixed together. There is no categories nor order in there.

Answer (score -1):

hero sostwidge : hiver cheese : cooked meat : war bread.

I know allot more but i think you can handle looking for a few.

Tip : you can find recipes in archives

Comment: If you can post more you should, as complete answers are the nature of stackexchange sites. If you don't want to spoiler the game use `>!` to write your answers with a spoiler tag.

Comment: Exactly what turbo said. This website is made for people to ask questions and get full answers to them. Answer in which someone only partially answers the question and suggests that the one who asked question should look for the rest of the answer himself is not very constructive and as such shouldn't even be posted.