# What can I make with the lab station?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

In Sword of the Stars, you have a cooking station where you can prepare all kinds of things. But there is also a lab station where you can make items. But you have to get the recipes but it can also be done by trial and error. If you get it wrong you lose your items and also if you make it at the wrong station.

Which resource combinations work with the lab station?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This are the lab station recipes i have found so far (i will update the answer when i find more):

**Adamantium Claws** = Living Steel + Cyber-Connector + Nano-Wire + Adamantium Resin
**Adamantium Sword** = Lighting Blade + Adamantium Resin + Bindings + Unstable Isotopes
**Ballistic Kit** = Rifle parts + Electronic parts + Servos
**Hinge Spike** = Heavy Claw + Shotgun Shell + Acid Sack
**Chitin Plate Armor** = Composite Cloth + Chitin + Bindings
**Cyber Scrambler** = Cyber Brain + Energy Cell + Electronic Parts
**Diagnostic Chip** = Logic Circuit + Cybernetic Brain
**Door Spike** = 2x Shotgun Shells + Punch Claw + Giant Mitochondria
**Electronic Bypass** = Electronic Parts + Cyber Brain
**Energy Pack** = 4x Energy Cells + Binding
**Heavy Slug Thrower** = Mag Rifle + Microfurnace + Nanowire + Superconductors
**Heavy Slugs** = Shell Casings + Molecular Neutronium + Element X
**Improvised Lockpick** = Razorteeth + Bindings + Bone Slivers
**Improvised Medkit** = Bindings + Serum + Antibiotics + Bone Slivers
**Laser Rifle** = Rifle Parts + Superconductors + Photonic Amplifier + Quantum Capacitors + Bindings
**Lifter Pack** = Element X + Composite Cloth + Nano-Wire + Power Source
**Pulse Resonator** = Soft Screen + Cybernetic Brain + Sonic Nodule
**Rage Beam** = Sonic Nodule + Hiver Brain Crystals + Bindings + Rifle Parts
**Razor Fists** = Razorteeth + Bindings + Composite Cloth
**Rosetta Brain** = Hiver Brain Crystals + Logic Circuit + Soft Screen + Energy Cell
**Sniper Rifle** = Rifle + Optics + Binding
**Sonic Gun** = Gun Parts + Sonic Nodule + Electronic Parts + Energy Cells
**X-Ray Rifle** = Laser Rifle + X-Ray Transducer + Photonic Amplifier + Bindings
**Base Defence Plan Gamma** = Grenade + Cyber Connectors + Sparker
**Energy System Tuner** = Superconductors + Gun Parts + Optics + Electronic Parts
**Ersatz Sharpening Kit** = 2 x Heavy Claw + 2 x Razor Claws + Bindings
**Grav Boots** = Energy cell + Element x + Superconductors + Bindings + boots
**Grenade** = Shotgunshells + Shotgunshells + Shotgunshells + Sparker + Casing Fragments
**Heavy Cannon** = cannon parts + superconductors + reflex micro-furnace + adamantium resin + servos
**Targeting Helmet** = Casing Fragments + Logic circuits + Optics + Bindings
**Quantum Scan Helmet** = Casing Fragment + Optics + Quantum Capacitor + Electronic parts
**Mine Trap** = Cyber-Connector + Grenade + Sparker
**RG Special** = Duct Tape + Duct Tape + Duct Tape + Bone Slivers + Bone Slivers
**Poison sword**= Sword + Poison Gland+ Poison Gland + Poison Gland + Duct Tape
**Pulse Rifle** = Laser Rifle + Photonic Amplifier + Superconductors + Bindings
**Aykay Rifle** = Rifle Parts + Structural Rods + Welding Goo + Bindings + Servos
**Blunderbuss** = Rifle Parts + Compression Chamber + Welding Goo + Duct Tape + Sparker

*Source*: multiple forums and personal finds

Comment: with (Sniper Rifle = Rifle + Optics + Binding) does the auto rifle count?

Comment: @zeke Nope, haves to be "Rifle".

Comment: tyvm ^^ you saved my gun from death

Comment: Hmmm, you have 2 of the same things I think : Hand Stunner = Energy Cell + Gun Parts + Electronic Parts + Sonic Nodule and Sonic Gun = Gun Parts + Sonic Nodule + Electronic Parts + Energy Cells

Comment: @Lyrion Aight thx, fixed.

Comment: Poison sword= sword+ poison gland+ poison gland+ poison gland+ duct tape. rest i know already mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

All mobs, items & recipes: [thePITopedia](http://thepit.0xff.me)

Comment: I'd be happy to up-vote this if you expand your answer to offer details instead of just a link.  This answer would become useless if your link went dead...

Comment: The fact that it's link-answer is not the only problem here. This question asks for lab only crafting recipes. The link you gave contains everything (lab recipes too, and items that aren't even used as ingredients), and to make it even worse they're all mixed together. There is no categories nor order in there. Your answers on this site should answer ONLY what is being asked, and they should be as constructive as possible. Not just a link to mess-filled site.

Answer (score 0):

The following recipes were accumulated from playthroughs, searching online, the Pitopedeia - http://thepit.0xff.me/, and the SotS The Pit wikia - http://sword-of-the-stars-the-pit.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_the_Stars:_The_Pit_Wiki.

***Via Lab Station / Creation Station / AI Lab***

**Absorber Weave** = Scaleskin + Scaleskin + Superconductors + Nano Wire + String Sink
**Absorption Plate** = Absorption Scale + Graphene Plates + Nano Wire + Chitin
**Adamantium Claws** = Adamantium Resin + Cyber Connectors + Living Steel Remnant + Nano Wire
**Adamantium Sword** = Adamantium Resin + Bindings + Lightning Blade + Unstable Isotopes
**AyKay Rifle** = Rifle Parts + Structural Rods + Welding Goo + Bindings + Servos
**Ballistic Repair Kit** = Electronic Parts + Rifle Parts + Servos
**Bio-Blaster** = Energy Tap + Biocontroller + Omni Gland + Photonic Amplifier + Scaleskin
**Blowdart Rifle** = Bone + Bindings + Compression Chamber + Myomer Bundles + Energy Cell
**Blunderbuss** = Rifle Parts + Compression Chamber + Welding Goo + Duct Tape + Sparker
**Bone Dagger** = Bone + Bindings + Razorteeth
**Bypass Circuit * 2** = Cybernetic Brain + Electronic Parts
**Caltrops * 3** = Bone Slivers + Bone Slivers + Casing Fragments + Bindings + Bindings
**Chitin Plate Armor** = Bindings + Composite Cloth + Chitin + Chitin + Chitin
**Cyber Scrambler** = Cybernetic Brain + Electronic Parts + Energy Cell
**Diagnostic Chip** = Cybernetic Brain + Logic Circuits
**Door Spike** = Giant Mitochondria + Punch Claw + Shotgun Shells + Shotgun Shells
**Emergency Teleporter * 2** = String Sink + Superconductors + Tachyon Capacitors + Quantum Capacitors + Energy Cell
**Energy Backpack** = Bindings + Energy Cell + Energy Cell + Energy Cell + Energy Cell
**Energy System Tuner** = Electronic Parts + Gun Parts + Optics + Superconductors
**Faux Tag** = Electronic Parts + Electronic Parts + Specimen Tag + System Transponder
**Fear Lantern** = Hoolari Gourd + Scent Gland + Sparker + Razorteeth
**Firebomb** = Sparker + Fuel Cell + Fuel Cell + Bindings
**Force Field Belt** = Superconductors + String Sink + Utility Belt + Reflex Micro-Furnace + Duct Tape
**Grav Boots** = Bindings + Combat Boots + Element X + Energy Cell + Superconductors
**Grenade** = Casing Fragments + Shotgun Shells + Shotgun Shells + Shotgun Shells + Sparker
**Hand Stunner** = Energy Cell + Gun Parts + Electronic Parts + Sonic Nodule
**Harmonic Resonator** = Adaptive Crystal + String Sink + Superconductors
**Harpy Drone** = Photonic Amplifier + Combat Processors + Casing Fragments + Reflex Micro-Furnace + Element X
**Heavy Cannon** = Adamantium Resin + Cannon Parts + Reflex Micro-Furnace + Servos + Superconductors
**Heavy Silencer** = Rifle Parts + Scaleskin + Duct Tape + Scaleskin + Vibranite
**Heavy Slug-Thrower** = Mag Rifle + Reflex Micro-Furnace + Nano Wire + Superconductors
**Heavy Slugs * 15** = Element X + Molecular Neutronium + Shell Casings
**Hinge Spike** = Acid Sack + Heavy Claw + Shotgun Shells
**Improvised Exo Armor** = Neural Netting + Neural Transmitters + Structural Rods + Reflex Micro-Furnace + Myomer Bundles
**Improvised Lockpick * 3** = Bindings + Bone Slivers + Razorteeth
**Improvised Medkit** = Antibiotics + Bindings + Bone Slivers + Serum
**Kinetic Plate** = Kinetic Scale + Vibranite + Nano Wire + Chitin
**Laser Rifle** = Bindings + Photonic Amplifier + Quantum Capacitors + Rifle Parts + Superconductors
**Lifter Pack** = Composite Cloth + Element X + Energy Cell + Nano Wire
**Lightning Blade** = String Sink + Living Steel Remnant + Sar + Welding Goo + AM Cells
**Liquidator** = Rifle Parts + Welding Goo + Compression Chamber + Servos
**M'Kkose Darter** = Exotic Protein + Rifle Parts + Compression Chamber + Fungal Shards + Duct Tape
**Mine Trap** = Cyber Connectors + Grenade + Sparker
**Poison Darts * 5** = Chemo Slugs + Injector Fangs + Poison Gland + Poison Gland
**Pulsar Pistol** = Adaptive Crystal + Gun Parts + String Sink + Quantum Capacitors + Reflex Micro-Furnace
**Pulse Resonator** = Cybernetic Brain + Softscreen + Sonic Nodule
**Pulse Rifle** = Bindings + Laser Rifle + Photonic Amplifier + Superconductors
**Purifier** = Compression Chamber + Fuel Cell + Sparker
**Quantum Scan Helmet** = Casing Fragments + Optics + Quantum Capacitors + Electronic Parts
**R G Special** = Duct Tape + Duct Tape + Duct Tape + Bone Slivers + Bone Slivers
**Rage Beam** = Rifle Parts + Hiver Brain Crystal + Sonic Nodule + Bindings
**Razor Fists** = Bindings + Composite Cloth + Razorteeth
**Regen Patch** = Adrenal Sack + Med Patch + Giant Mitochondria
**Regen Plate** = Nurturing Embrace + Biocontroller + Scaleskin + Omni Gland
**Rosetta Brain** = Softscreen + Hiver Brain Crystal + Logic Circuits + Energy Cell
**Seismic Boots** = Vibranite + Sonic Nodule + Combat Boots + Reflex Micro-Furnace + Superconductors
**Seismic Gloves** = Vibranite + Sonic Nodule + Composite Cloth + AM Cells + Quantum Capacitors
**Sharpening Kit** = Heavy Claw + Heavy Claw + Razorteeth + Razorteeth + Bindings
**Silenced Auto Rifle** = Heavy Silencer + Welding Goo + Welding Goo + Structural Rods
**Silenced Machine Pistol** = Heavy Silencer + Welding Goo
**Silenced Pistol** = Silencer + Welding Goo
**Silencer** = Gun Parts + Bindings + Bindings + Bone
**Sniper Rifle** = Rifle + Bindings + Optics
**Spore Dagger** = Bone + Fungal Shards + Bindings + Bindings
**Squawker Drone** = Optics + Neural Transmitters + Casing Fragments + Hiver Brain Crystal + Element X
**Targeting Dart** = Electronic Parts + Specimen Tag + Darts
**Targeting Helmet** = Casing Fragments + Optics + Logic Circuits + Bindings
**Turret** = Auto Pistol + Combat Processors + Casing Fragments + Welding Goo + Optics
**Turret Override** = Electronic Parts + Energy Cell + System Transponder
**Venom Sword** = Sword + Poison Gland + Poison Gland + Poison Gland + Duct Tape
**X-Rifle** = Laser Rifle + Photonic Amplifier + X-Ray Transducer + Bindings

The following are partial recipes I know, if anyone can provide the names of the missing ingredients, or any other recipes I'm missing, let me know, and I'll update the above with them.

**Disruptor Plate** = Duct Tape + Composite Cloth + ??? + Reflex Micro-Furnace + Duct Tape