# How can I mitigate disease?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I've been playing The Pit lately, and I've found I die consistently from disease.  In fact, it's my *sole* cause of death.  There seems to be no rhyme or reason as to when your disease level goes up or down, and once you hit level 10, you're dead.

What factors contribute to lowering your disease level?  What items can I use to either bolster my defense to it pre-infection, or fight it off after I've been infected?  I know there are anti-bodies, which drop poison levels; is there something similiar for disease?

Answer (score 5):

Vitamins are reported to prevent disease from getting worse. Also, having a higher Might stat reduces the risk of disease. Increasing your Might stat past 50 or 60 should help significantly. Engineer and Scouts are more susceptible to disease because of their lower Might stats.

Source: [Steam Forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/233700/discussions/0/828934089627002436/) and [Steam Forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/233700/discussions/0/828934424143638272/)

Answer (score 3):

In terms of mitigating disease, the Might stat is the one that is checked when a resistance check is made, and hence decides whether you reduce, maintain, or increase your disease level. Having a high Might will make you less likely to die of disease, and also poison.

That's the only disease mitigation I know. There are disease curing items in game, such as ;
**Antibiotics** - Random drop, some classes start with some, can reduce two levels of disease
**Aggressive Antibiotics** - made by combining Anti-Bodies and Moldy Bread at a Cooking Station or with an EZ Cooker, can reduce four levels of disease
**Terran Med Kit** - Random drop, some classes start with it, has five uses, each use can reduce one level of disease
**Improvised Med Kit** - made by combining Antibiotics, Bindings, Bone Slivers, and Serum at a Lab Station, has five uses, each use can reduce one level of disease
**Vitamins** - Random drop, very rare, has other possible uses, increases your chance of succeeding the next disease check (i.e. not a guarantee)
**Immunojolt** - Random drop, high medicine check, immunity to disease for a time, cures any existing disease
**Immunoagent** - Random drop, immunity to disease for a time, cures any existing disease
**Resistance Booster** - Random drop, increases your chance of succeeding the next disease check (i.e. not a guarantee)

Answer (score 1):

The [food item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/108198/30863) **Aggressive Antibiotics** can reduce up to 4 disease levels.

Corresponding skill is *Medical*.

To cook two of these, you need 1 **Anti-Bodies** and 1 **Moldy Bread**.

[image: Anti-Bodies] + [image: Moldy Bread] = [image: Aggressive Antibiotics]